# Why can't I use the method __cmp__ in Python 3 as for Python 2?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, partial-ordering

The following piece of code

```
class point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def dispc(self):
        return ('(' + str(self.x) + ',' + str(self.y) + ')')

    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return ((self.x > other.x) and (self.y > other.y))
```

works fine in Python 2, but in Python 3 I get an error:

```
>>> p=point(2,3)
>>> q=point(3,4)
>>> p>q
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: point() > point()
```

---

It only works for `==` and `!=`.

Comment: That `__cmp__` was broken in Python 2 already.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

You need to provide the rich comparison methods for ordering in Python 3, which are  [`__lt__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__), [`__gt__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__gt__), [`__le__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__le__), [`__ge__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ge__), [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__), and [`__ne__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ne__). See also: [PEP 207 -- Rich Comparisons](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0207/).

`__cmp__` is **no** longer used.

---

More specifically, `__lt__` takes `self` and `other` as arguments, and needs to return whether `self` is less than `other`. For example:

```
class Point(object):
    ...
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return ((self.x < other.x) and (self.y < other.y))
```

(This isn't a sensible comparison implementation, but it's hard to tell what you were going for.)

So if you have the following situation:

```
p1 = Point(1, 2)
p2 = Point(3, 4)

p1 < p2
```

This will be equivalent to:

```
p1.__lt__(p2)
```

which would return `True`.

`__eq__` would return `True` if the points are equal and `False` otherwise. The other methods work analogously.

---

If you use the [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) decorator, you only need to implement e.g. the `__lt__` and `__eq__` methods:

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class Point(object):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        ...

    def __eq__(self, other):
        ...
```

Comment: Now you need to define `__hash__` to use your object in a set or as a dict key.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about using `functools.total_ordering`!  I just tried it out on Python 3.6, and I only needed to define the `__lt__(self, other)` method.  (Probably because if `a < b` and `b < a` are both false, then it follows that `a == b` must be true.)

Comment: it actually "must define at least one ordering operation: < > <= >=" - by error message

Answer (score 17):

This was a major and deliberate change in Python 3.  See [here](http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons) for more details.

> - The ordering comparison operators (`<`, `<=`, `>=`, `>`) raise a `TypeError` exception when the operands don’t have a meaningful natural ordering. Thus, expressions like `1 < ''`, `0 > None` or `len <= len` are no longer valid, and e.g. `None < None` raises `TypeError` instead of returning `False`. A corollary is that sorting a heterogeneous list no longer makes sense – all the elements must be comparable to each other. Note that this does not apply to the `==` and `!=` operators: objects of different incomparable types always compare unequal to each other.
> - `builtin.sorted()` and `list.sort()` no longer accept the `cmp` argument providing a comparison function. Use the `key` argument instead. N.B. the `key` and `reverse` arguments are now “keyword-only”.
> - The `cmp()` function should be treated as gone, and the `__cmp__()` special method is no longer supported. Use `__lt__()` for sorting, `__eq__()` with `__hash__()`, and other rich comparisons as needed. (If you really need the `cmp()` functionality, you could use the expression `(a > b) - (a < b)` as the equivalent for `cmp(a, b)`.)

Answer (score 12):

In Python3 the six rich comparison operators

```
__lt__(self, other) 
__le__(self, other) 
__eq__(self, other) 
__ne__(self, other) 
__gt__(self, other) 
__ge__(self, other)
```

must be provided individually. This can be abbreviated by using `functools.total_ordering`.

This however turns out rather unreadable and unpractical most of the time. Still you have to put similar code pieces in 2 funcs - or use a further helper func.

So mostly I prefer to use the mixin class `PY3__cmp__` shown below. This reestablishes the single `__cmp__` method framework, which was and is quite clear and practical in most cases. One can still override selected rich comparisons.

Your example would just become:

```
 class point(PY3__cmp__):
      ... 
      # unchanged code
```

## The PY3__cmp__ mixin class:

```
PY3 = sys.version_info[0] >= 3
if PY3:
    def cmp(a, b):
        return (a > b) - (a < b)
    # mixin class for Python3 supporting __cmp__
    class PY3__cmp__:   
        def __eq__(self, other):
            return self.__cmp__(other) == 0
        def __ne__(self, other):
            return self.__cmp__(other) != 0
        def __gt__(self, other):
            return self.__cmp__(other) > 0
        def __lt__(self, other):
            return self.__cmp__(other) < 0
        def __ge__(self, other):
            return self.__cmp__(other) >= 0
        def __le__(self, other):
            return self.__cmp__(other) <= 0
else:
    class PY3__cmp__:
        pass
```

Comment: I liked the way you wrote the operators. However, please explain this statement (a > b) - (a < b). It took me a while to understand this.

Comment: @theBuzzyCoder `bool` is just a subclass of `int`, so `True` and `False` are basically 1 and 0, respectively. Since `cmp` returns a negative value if its first argument is less than its second argument, zero if the arguments are equal, or a positive value otherwise, you can see that `False - False == 0`, `True - False == 1`, and `False - True == -1` provide the correct return values for `cmp`.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 was ahead of time, since the `__cmp__` operator to implement [three-way comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison) is currently gaining popularity, in C++ (spaceship operator) and elsewhere. See [Universal Comparison Operator In Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68535022/universal-comparison-operator-in-python).

I like the mixin class from kxr in principle, but for my taste a decorator would be more fitting

The `PY3__cmp__` decorator is modeled after @krx's answer and the [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) decorator.

```py
def cmp(a, b):
  return (a > b) - (a < b)

_convert = {
  '__eq__': lambda self, other: self.__cmp__(other) == 0,
  '__ne__': lambda self, other: self.__cmp__(other) != 0,
  '__lt__': lambda self, other: self.__cmp__(other) < 0,
  '__le__': lambda self, other: self.__cmp__(other) <= 0,
  '__gt__': lambda self, other: self.__cmp__(other) > 0,
  '__ge__': lambda self, other: self.__cmp__(other) >= 0,
}

def PY3__cmp__(cls):
  """Class decorator that fills in missing ordering methods when
     Python2-style `__cmp__(self, other)` method is provided."""
  if not hasattr(cls, '__cmp__'):
    raise ValueError('must define the __cmp__ Python2-style method')
  if sys.version_info < (3, 0, 0):
    return cls
  for op, opfunc in _convert.items():
    # Overwrite the `raise NotImplemented` comparisons inherited from object
    if getattr(cls, op, None) is getattr(object, op, None):
      setattr(cls, op, opfunc)
  return cls
```

(And yes, my codebase still holds onto some pre PEP-8 ideas about indentation.)