# Priority Queue Doesn't Recognize __cmp__ Function In Python

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, operator-overloading

I am attempting to implement a priority queue in Python. I am following an [example](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_PriorityQueue_heapq_Data_Structure.php) that I found online. The `Skill` class overrides the `__cmp__` method so that the priority queue can order itself. I am getting a error when I run:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: Skill() < Skill()
```

I've found several examples online that say as long as you overload the `__cmp__()` method the priority queue should be good.

```
try:
    import Queue as Q  # ver. < 3.0
except ImportError:
    import queue as Q

class Skill(object):
    def __init__(self, priority, description):
        self.priority = priority
        self.description = description
        print ('New Level:', description)
        return
    def __cmp__(self, other):
        return cmp(self.priority, other.priority)

q = Q.PriorityQueue()

q.put(Skill(5, 'Proficient'))
q.put(Skill(10, 'Expert'))
q.put(Skill(1, 'Novice'))

while not q.empty():
    next_level = q.get()
    print ('Processing level:', next_level.description)
```

I'm currently running Python 3.4.1 on my computer.

Comment: Is that your actual indentation? Also, note that `__cmp__` is ignored in 3.x, and was replaced by rich comparison: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/8276983/3001761

Comment: That is my actual indentation. I'm new to Python, is another indentation more common? So I should use a rich comparison rather than cmp?

Comment: Indentation is crucial in Python, the code you've posted won't work. Yes, you have to use the rich comparison methods if you're writing for 3.x.

Comment: What specifically is wrong about my indentation? What kind of indentation do you use?

Comment: The body of `Skill.__init__` isn't indented, and `__cmp__` is shown as being outside of the class altogether. What do you mean *"what kind"*?! Indentation is **part of Python's syntax**.

Comment: You're right, I copied from my text editor and StackOverflow's code indentation messed up my indentation. The issues you point out are correct in my code.

Comment: So when you said *"that is my actual indentation"*, it actually isn't? Please **edit the question**.

Comment: No it wasn't. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`__cmp__` was removed in Python3, you should use the rich comparison dunder methods instead `__lt__`, `__le__`, `__eq__`, `__ne__`, `__gt__`, `__ge__`.

They work as follows:

```
a < b  # a.__lt__(b)
a <= b # a.__le__(b)
a == b # a.__eq__(b)
a != b # a.__ne__(b)
a > b  # a.__gt__(b)
a >= b # a.__ge__(b)
```

You can also use the the class decorator [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) which allows you to specify `__eq__` and any one of `__lt__, __le__, __gt__, __ge__` and it will infer the rest of the rich comparison methods.

```
import functools

@functools.total_ordering
class NewNumber(object):
    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.num < getattr(other, 'num', other)
        # fancy way of doing self.num < other.num if other.num exists,
        #   else to do self.num < other
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.num == getattr(other, 'num', other)
```

Answer (score 1):

`cmp` and `__cmp__` were only used in Python 2.x; they no longer exist in Python 3.x.  Nowadays, you overload the comparison operators directly by implementing `__eq__`, `__ne__`, `__lt__`, `__gt__`, `__ge__`, and `__le__`.

You can read about this change on the What's New In Python 3.0 page under [Ordering Comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons):

> The `cmp()` function should be treated as gone, and the `__cmp__()`
>   special method is no longer supported. Use `__lt__()` for sorting,
>   `__eq__()` with `__hash__()`, and other rich comparisons as needed.