# python - native approach to comparing objects

Tags: python

I have a simple python class, that I want to be able to compare. So I implemented compare operators. I then realized that I've been doing that same thing for so many classes, and it feels a lot like code duplication.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, index, data):
        self.index = index
        self.data = data

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.index < other.index

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.index > other.index

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.index <= other.index

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.index >= other.index

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.index == other.index

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self.index != other.index
```

So I think a simple solution would be something like this:

```
class Comparable(object):
    def _compare(self, other):
        raise UnimplementedError()

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self._compare(other) < 0

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self._compare(other) > 0

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self._compare(other) <= 0

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self._compare(other) >= 0

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self._compare(other) == 0

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self._compare(other) != 0

class Foo1(Comparable):
    def _compare(self, other):
        return self.index - other.index

class Foo2(Comparable):
    def _compare(self, other):
        # ...

class Foo3(Comparable):
    def _compare(self, other):
        # ...
```

But it seems so basic, that I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel here.

I'm wondering if there a more 'native' way to achieve that.

Comment: For something basic like this you could simply implement `__cmp__` instead of each individual op

Comment: @Jkdc ["The `__cmp__()` special method is no longer honored in Python 3."](http://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparisons.html)

Comment: @Jkdc That is exactly what I was looking for! Too bad for the Python 3 support :(

Comment: You could use a [PY3__cmp__ mixin class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39166382/4349415)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [in the docs](http://portingguide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/comparisons.html) you can use [`functools.total_ordering`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) to save some boilerplate in writing all of the comparisons

> To avoid the hassle of providing all six functions, you can implement `__eq__`, `__ne__`, and only one of the ordering operators, and use the `functools.total_ordering()` decorator to fill in the rest.

To be explicit, the six functions they are referring to are: `__eq__`, `__ne__`, `__lt__`, `__le__`, `__gt__`, and `__ge__`.

Answer (score 1):

So, you want some automation while creating **rich comparison** methods. You can have this behaviour by using `functools.total_ordering()` higher-order function. See the [reference](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) for more details.