# in put if self.maxsize > 0: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

My code gets stuck on this line:-

```
prefetch_queue.put((idx, dummy_data), block=True)
```

The error is at the end

where idx is 0

and dummy_data contains the following:-

```
data:array([[[-1., -1., -1.],\n        [-1., -1., -1.],\n        [-1.,
-1., -1.],\n        ...,\n        [-1., -1., -1.],\n        [-1., -1., 
-1.],\n        [-1., -1., -1.]],\n\n       [[-1., -1., -1.],\n        
[-1., -1., -1.],\n        [-1., -1., -1.],\n        ...,\n        [-1., 
-1., -1.],\n        [-1., -1., -1.],\n        [-1., -1.,
-1.]],\n\n       [[-1., -1., -1.],\n        [-1., -1., -1.],\n        
[-1., -1., -1.],\n        ...,\n        [-1., -1., -1.],\n        [-1., 
-1., -1.],\n        [-1., -1., -1.]],\n\n       ...,\n\n       [[-1., - 
-1., -1.],\n        [-1., -1., -1.],\n        [-1., -1.,
-1.],\n        ...,\n        [-1., -1., -1.],\n        [-1., -1., -1.],\n        
[-1., -1., -1.]],\n\n       [[-1., -1., -1.],\n        [-1., -1., -1.],\n        
[-1., -1., -1.],\n        ...,\n        [-1., -1., -1.],\n        [-1., 
-1., -1.],\n        [-1., -1.,
-1.]],\n\n       [[-1., -1., -1.],\n        [-1., -1., -1.],\n        
[-1., -1., -1.],\n        ...,\n        [-1., -1., -1.],\n        [-1., 
-1., -1.],\n        [-1., -1., -1.]]]) [0:375] :[array([[-1.,
-1., -1...1., -1.]]), array([[-1., -1., -1...1., -1.]]), array([[-1., 
-1., -1...1., -1.]]), array([[-1., -1., -1...1., -1.]]), array([[-1., 
-1., -1...1., -1.]]), array([[-1., -1., -1...1., -1.]]), array([[-1., 
-1., -1...1., -1.]]), array([[-1., -1., -1...1., -1.]]), array([[-1., 
-1., -1...1., -1.]]), array([[-1., -1., -1...1., -1.]]), array([[-1., 
-1., -1...1., -1.]]), array([[-1., -1., -1...1., -1.]]), array([[-1., 
-1., -1...1., -1.]]), array([[-1., -1., -1...1., -1.]]), ...] 
dtype:dtype('float64') max:'ndarray too big, calculating max would slow 
down debugging' min:'ndarray too big, calculating min would slow down 
debugging' shape:(375, 1242, 3) size:1397250
__internals__:{'T': array([[[-1., -1., -...., -1.]]]), 'base': None, 
'ctypes': <numpy.core._interna...184E30CC0>, 'data': <memory at 
0x000001C184E7F048>, 'dtype': dtype('float64'), 'flags':   C_CONTIGUOUS : 
Tru...PY : False, 'flat': <numpy.flatiter obje...F9832E140>, 'imag': 
array([[[0., 0., 0.]...0., 0.]]]), 'itemsize': 8, 'nbytes': 11178000, 
'ndim': 3, 'real': array([[[-1.,
-1., -...., -1.]]]), 'shape': (375, 1242, 3), 'size': 1397250, ...} 
'T':array([[[-1., -1., -1., ..., -1., -1., -1.],\n        [-1., -1.,
-1., ..., -1., -1., -1.],\n        [-1., -1., -1., ..., -1., -1., -1.],\n        
...,\n        [-1., -1., -1., ..., -1., -1., -1.],\n        [-1., -1., 
-1., ..., -1., -1., -1.],\n        [-1., -1., -1., ...,
-1., -1., -1.]],\n\n       [[-1., -1., -1., ..., -1., -1., -1.],\n        
[-1., -1., -1., ..., -1., -1., -1.],\n        [-1., -1., -1., ...,
-1., -1., -1.],\n        ...,\n        [-1., -1., -1., ..., -1., -1., 
-1.],\n        [-1., -1., -1., ..., -1., -1., -1.],\n        [-1., -1., 
-1., ..., -1., -1., -1.]],\n\n       [[-1., -1., -1., ..., -1., -1., 
-1.],\n        [-1., -1., -1., ..., -1., -1., -1.],\n        [-1., -1., 
-1., ..., -1., -1., -1.],\n        ...,\n        [-1., -1.,
-1., ..., -1., -1., -1.],\n        [-1., -1., -1., ..., -1., -1., -1.],\n        
[-1., -1., -1., ..., -1., -1., -1.]]]) 'base':None 'ctypes': 
<numpy.core._internal._ctypes object at 0x000001C184E30CC0> 'data': 
<memory at 0x000001C184E7F048> 'dtype':dtype('float64') 'flags':  
C_CONTIGUOUS : True\n  F_CONTIGUOUS : False\n  OWNDATA : True\n  
WRITEABLE : True\n  ALIGNED : True\n  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False\n  
UPDATEIFCOPY : False 'flat':<numpy.flatiter object at 0x000001BF9832E140> 
'imag':array([[[0., 0., 0.],\n        [0., 0.,
0.],\n        [0., 0., 0.],\n        ...,\n        [0., 0., 0.],\n        
[0., 0., 0.],\n        [0., 0., 0.]],\n\n       [[0., 0., 0.],\n       
[0., 0., 0.],\n        [0., 0., 0.],\n        ...,\n        [0., 0.,
0.],\n        [0., 0., 0.],\n        [0., 0., 0.]],\n\n       [[0., 0., 
0.],\n        [0., 0., 0.],\n        [0., 0., 0.],\n        ...,\n        
[0., 0., 0.],\n        [0., 0., 0.],\n        [0., 0., 0.]],\n\n       
...,\n\n       [[0., 0., 0.],\n        [0., 0., 0.],\n        [0., 0.,
0.],\n        ...,\n        [0., 0., 0.],\n        [0., 0., 0.],\n        
[0., 0., 0.]],\n\n       [[0., 0., 0.],\n        [0., 0., 0.],\n       
[0., 0., 0.],\n        ...,\n        [0., 0., 0.],\n        [0., 0.,
0.],\n        [0., 0., 0.]],\n\n       [[0., 0., 0.],\n        [0., 0., 
0.],\n        [0., 0., 0.],\n        ...,\n        [0., 0., 0.],\n        
[0., 0., 0.],\n        [0., 0., 0.]]]) 'itemsize':8 'nbytes':11178000
```

I've looked through the stack overflow posts, and searched the code below looking for > operators, or equalities to None but can't find any.

There are two lines in the code from here:-
https://github.com/liuziwei7/voxel-flow/voxel_flow_train.py

```
Trainingset_load_fn_frame1 = partial(TrainingSet_F1.process_func)
Trainingset_p_queue_frame1 = PrefetchQueue(Trainingset_load_fn_frame1, 
data_list_frame1, FLAGS.batch_size, shuffle=False, 
num_workers=num_workers)
```

that then enter into the code
https://github.com/liuziwei7/voxel-flow/tree/master/utils/prefetch_queue_shuffle.py:-

```
from __future__ import print_function

import glob
import numpy as np
import os 
import queue
import random
import scipy
from scipy import misc
import threading 

class DummpyData(object):
  def __init__(self, data):
    self.data = data
  def __cmp__(self, other):
    return 0

def prefetch_job(load_fn, prefetch_queue, data_list, shuffle, prefetch_size):
  """
  """
  data_count = 0
  total_count = len(data_list)
  idx = 0
  while True:
    if shuffle:
      if data_count == 0:
        random.shuffle(data_list)
      data = load_fn(data_list[data_count]) #Load your data here
      if type(data) is list:
        for data_point in data: 
          idx = random.randint(0, prefetch_size)
          dummy_data = DummpyData(data_point)
          prefetch_queue.put((idx, dummy_data), block=True)
      else:
        idx = random.randint(0, prefetch_size)
        dummy_data = DummpyData(data)
        prefetch_queue.put((idx, dummy_data), block=True)
    else:
      data = load_fn(data_list[data_count]) #Load your data here
      dummy_data = DummpyData(data)
      prefetch_queue.put((idx, dummy_data), block=True) # it gets stuck here
      idx = (idx + 1) % prefetch_size

    data_count = (data_count + 1) % total_count

class PrefetchQueue(object):
  def __init__(self, load_fn, data_list, batch_size, prefetch_size=None, shuffle=True, num_workers=4):
    self.data_list = data_list
    self.shuffle = shuffle
    self.prefetch_size = prefetch_size
    self.load_fn = load_fn
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    if prefetch_size is None:
      self.prefetch_size = num_workers * batch_size # was set to 4

    # Start prefetching thread
    # self.prefetch_queue = Queue.Queue(maxsize=prefetch_size)
    self.prefetch_queue = queue.PriorityQueue(maxsize=prefetch_size)
    for k in range(num_workers):
      t = threading.Thread(target=prefetch_job,
        args=(self.load_fn, self.prefetch_queue, self.data_list,
              self.shuffle, self.prefetch_size))
      t.daemon = True
      t.start()

  def get_batch(self):
    data_list = []
    for k in range(0, self.batch_size):
      # if self.prefetch_queue.empty():
      #   print('Prefetch Queue is empty, waiting for data to be read.')
      _, data_dummy = self.prefetch_queue.get(block=True)
      data = data_dummy.data
      data_list.append(np.expand_dims(data,0))
    return np.concatenate(data_list, axis=0)
```

I expected it to run, but instead it gives the following error:-

```
Exception in thread Thread-35:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\...\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\...\Python37\lib\threading.py", line 865, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "c:\...\utils\prefetch_queue_shuffle.py", line 41, in prefetch_job
prefetch_queue.put((idx, dummy_data), block=True)
File "C:\...\Python37\lib\queue.py", line 133, in put
if self.maxsize > 0:
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because line 47 in prefetch_queue_shuffle.py has prefetch_size=None,

class PrefetchQueue(object):
  def **init**(self, load_fn, data_list, batch_size, prefetch_size=None, shuffle=True, num_workers=4):

self.prefetch_queue = queue.PriorityQueue(maxsize=prefetch_size)

which then means that line 133 in queue.py becomes None

if self.maxsize > 0:

However, this is not accepted in Python 3x

This leads to this error

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'DummpyData' and 'DummpyData'
Which could be to do with line 15 of prefetch_queue_shuffle.py :-
  def **cmp**(self, other):
    return 0
[Why can't I use the method __cmp__ in Python 3 as for Python 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276983/why-cant-i-use-the-method-cmp-in-python-3-as-for-python-2)

changing this to

from functools import total_ordering

class DummpyData(object):
  def **init**(self, data):
    self.data = data
  @total_ordering
  def **lt**(self, other): # was **cmp**(self, other):
    return 0

This then works, however, it doesn’ t seem to increase GPU usage efficiency.  Infact it seems to be slower this way…

More workers in this case reduce the time that the GPU is working