# Adding dictionaries in lists using heappush

Tags: python, list, dictionary, heap

I've been trying to add dictionaries to a list using the heappush function. The first heappush statement works fine, and the print statement after that is executed.

```
#random tests
node1 = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
node2 = {'c':4, 'd':5, 'e':6}
lists = []
heappush(lists, node1)
print(lists)
heappush(lists, node2)
```

However, when I try to execute the second heappush statement, it gives me the following error.

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-c680e53f9699> in <module>()
      5 heappush(lists, node1)
      6 print(lists)
----> 7 heappush(lists, node2)

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'dict' and 'dict'
```

Why is that? I know I can use append function to append dictionaries to the list, but I want to use heappush instead

Comment: When the heap(min/max) is created, two elements are compared using '<' operator so that max element can go at top in case of max-heap and min element can go at top in case of min-heap. Now, when you take two dictionary elements, how would you compare keys and values. is "key1" < "key2" or "val1" < "val2". That's why the error.

Comment: Why do you want to use a heap? What is the purpose? If your goal is to just add dicts to a list, then use `lists.append`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`heap`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) data structure stores the elements in the list in a specific format, so that the `pop()` and `push()` functions are both `O(log n)`. When putting a new element in the `heap`, we need to compare it with the other objects in the `heap` to determine position of the new item in the `list`, which is done using the comparison operators `<`.

Python dicts don't have comparison operators defined to decide which dict is smaller/larger than the other. What is your use case for putting `dicts` into a `heap`? If you want to have some kind of sorted order with dicts you will need to define the [comparator methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8277028/10522970) for the dict on your own.